# Search using php . comparing keyward to multiple columns in same table

Tags: php, mysql, search, variables

```
                                                                      <?php
//get data
session_start();

$button = $_GET['submit'];
$search = $_GET['search'];
if (!$button)
    echo "YOU DIDNT SUBMIT A KEYWORD";
else
{
   if (strlen($search)<=2)
       echo "SEARCH TERM TOO SHORT";
   else
   {
       echo"You searched for <b>$search</b><hr size='1'>";


   //connect to database
   include("connect.php");



    // a bit of filtering
 $search = strtoupper($search);
 $search= strip_tags($search);
 $search = trim ($search);

$search_exploded = explode(" ",$search);

foreach ($search_exploded as $search_each)

       {
          //construct query
           $x++;
           if ($x==1)
             $construct .= "CONCAT(role_category1, role_category2, role_category3, role_category4) LIKE '%$search_each%'";
           else
               $construct .= " OR CONCAT(role_category1, role_category2, role_category3, role_category4) LIKE '%$search_each%'";

       }
   //echo out construct
$construct = "SELECT * FROM  jobdescription WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($construct);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
    echo "No results found.";
else
    {
     echo "$foundnum results found!<p>";

     while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
         {

         $jobdescriptionid = $runrows['jobdescriptionid'];

         $companyid = $runrows['companyid'];
         $companyid = $runrows['companyid'];
         $role_1= $runrows['role_1'];
         $role_location_1 = $runrows['role_location_1'];
         $role_category_1 = $runrows['role_category_1'];
         $role_term_1 = $runrows['role_term_1'];
         $role_description_1 = $runrows['role_description_1'];
          $role_2= $runrows['role_2'];
         $role_location_2 = $runrows['role_location_2'];
         $role_category_2 = $runrows['role_category_2'];
         $role_term_2 = $runrows['role_term_2'];
         $role_description_2 = $runrows['role_description_2'];

         echo "
         <b>$companyid
          <b>$jobseekerfirstname $jobseekerlastname </b><br>
         $role_1<br>
         $role_location_1<br>
         $role_category_1<br>

          $role_2<br>
         $role_location_2<br>
         $role_category_2<br>";




 }
        }}}
```

`?>`   am using the php script but its still now identifying what am searching for. Am trying to search for fields in the same table but different columns (heads of these columns are role_category1,role_category2.....) any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

```
$construct .= "'role_category_1' || 'role_category_2' || 'role_category_3' || 'role_category_4' OR preferedlocation LIKE '%$search_each%'";
```

in MySQL, concatenation is done via the CONCAT() function - you're doing bitwise `OR` operations on strings, so your construct is treated as:

```
string || string || string || string LIKE '%blahblahblah%'
```

which becomes

```
0 || 0 || 0 || 0 LIKE '%blahblah%';
0 || (0 LIKE '%blahblah%')
0
```

As well, since you put single quotes around the field names, MySQL will treat them as strings, not as field names, so you were in effect trying to match your input text string against a fixed string that looks like

```
role1_category1role_category2role_category3role_category4
```

You want

```
$construct .= "CONCAT(role_category1, role_category2, role_category3, role_category4) LIKE '%blahblah%'";
```

instead. Note the lack of quotes around the field names.

Comment: postgres and other databases use || for concatenation, so it's not a crazy error :-)

Comment: Yah. Too bad the various DB vendors can't get their respective crania out of their own posteriors and agree on a standard that's universally supported.

Comment: am using the php script but its still now identifying what am searching for. Am trying to search for fields in the same table but different columns (heads of these columns are role_category1,role_category2.....) any suggestions

Comment: What's the query look like when you finish building it? Does it actually work when you run it manually?

Comment: @Marc B that didnt work. am trying to search for all four columns for the keyword entered. help please its wrecking my head

Comment: {
              //construct query
               $x++;
               if ($x==1)
                   $construct .= "CONCAT(role_category1, role_category2, role_category3, role_category4) LIKE '%$search_each%'";
               else
                  $construct .= " OR CONCAT(role_category1, role_category2, role_category3, role_category4) LIKE '%$search_each%'";

           }
       //echo out construct
    $construct = "SELECT * FROM  jobdescription WHERE $construct";
    $run = mysql_query($construct);

Comment: That's the code to generate it, edit your question and paste in the actual query, e.g. what's the outpuut of `echo $construct`?